# Unlikely Events - Where does the Natural Force of Mean Reversion Kick In?

Tags: probability

If you play a 100x game of coin flip using a fair coin with a friend. You decide to opt out from picking H-or-T on any of the games until the 51st flip but you get to see the outcome of the flips throughout. Before the 51st flip, you look back and sum the total # of heads which happens to total exactly 50! Yes, all 50 coin flips were happened to be all heads, and the coin is a 100% fair. The probability of such an event is $1/2^5$.

Question do you bet tails for the remaining 50 flips in the hope that the total number of H to the total number of tails tends back to a 1:1 ratio??

What I want to know is if the math(s) argue an event is extremely unlikely does that generate a bias towards mean reversion? If you sum the total # of heads is beyond what 2 standard deviations suggests at the $nth$ flip does that increase the likelihood of mean reversion. If the answer is no, each coin flip is purely independent of the other, which is what your all going to say, than what "anchors" down the outcomes that the next 50 coin flips won't be also 50 as well!! Imagine you skip to the 100th flip and that all your concerned with at that point is the total of H's vs T's at n=100. How do you justify the magical "mana" effect of mean-reversion that pushes most outcomes toward 1:1? Is this magical mana just amortized over time at each flip preventing such low probability events of ever occurring to begin with?

Answer (score 2):

If the coin is truly fair, there is no advantage in betting one way or the other on any given flip.  The reason for 'mean reversion' is that it is likely that say the next $1000$ flips will be close to $500-500$ bringing the total to around $550-500$ which is a lot closer to $50\%$ than the original $50-0$.

Actually I might bet on heads some more, because it sure is looking like a biased coin from where I'm sitting!

Comment: Ha! Your funny paw but for this scenario the coin is fair, we are just looking at one  scenario of an incredibly low probability event. What is mean reversion, this is what I want to know if nothing is anchoring the number of heads from going to a full 100.

Comment: @jessica: The first paragraph is my answer for a fair coin.

Answer (score 0):

If the first 50 flips were all heads, then, chances are, you're going to get about 75 heads, plain and simple.

One way to think of this is that there is a defined and measurable outcome space for this game.  There are $2^{100}$ ways that the game could play out.  Including 100 heads.  And the average of every single one of these outcomes is 50 heads and 50 tails.  And in this space there are several $(2^{50})$ games that start of with 50 straight heads.  But there are just as many that start out with 50 straight tails.

Comment: I understand turkey, I understand what your saying but still... What does it mean for something to be an average of a 50 heads on a game of a 100 coin flip with a $stdv=sqrt(np(1-p))=+/-5$. We are simply saying if we play this game of 100 flips thousands of times that 68% of the outcomes ( numbers of heads at the end of the game) should be be within 95 and 105. but it doesn't mention how far outliers outside these bands can continue running. Or if they at some point will ever revert back to within what the numbers intially predicted before the simulations were ran.

Comment: Yeah, I'm probably not skilled enough to give a satisfactory response.  But I can say, yes, a sample that is completely skewed will eventually revert back to the mean as trials continue.  But not because of any pull due to a previous imbalance.  Only because the anomaly will be dwarfed by the larger sample that is closer to the mean.